# Track functionality missing from latest SDK update

Tags: smooch

I updated my pods today and got the latest 6.0.0 version of the SDK. However this seems to be missing the "track" function that was used to interact with the whispers setup on the dashboard. What is the alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whispers support, including the `track` API, was removed from all three Smooch SDKs in the latest major version releases, since the Whispers feature is currently deprecated and set to be removed from the platform on October 1st. The deprecation was communicated to all Whispers users at the beginning of July 2017.

If you send an email to help@smooch.io describing your use case, there may be the possibility of a workaround, but the newest SDKs were not designed to support Whispers or Whispers-style use cases, so workarounds won't be possible in every case.